# SQL Server SUM Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to run through a table and get the sum of the `mins` column however it always tells me that `mins` is not a valid column name

```
SELECT 
    acs.cid, 
    DATEDIFF (n, acs.StartTime, acs.EndTime ) as prepromomins,
    CASE 
        WHEN (p.multiplier is null) THEN DATEDIFF (n , acs.StartTime, acs.EndTime)
        ELSE (DATEDIFF ( n , acs.StartTime , acs.EndTime ) * p.multiplier) 
    END AS mins 
FROM 
    activecards as acs
    LEFT JOIN Promotions as p 
    ON acs.StartTime > p.StartTime and acs.EndTime < p.EndTime
```

Comment: Can you show us the query where you're trying to perform SUM on 'mins'?

Comment: Is this your full query? Please show us the full query and the table schemas in question.

Comment: `DATEDIFF ( minute , acs.StartTime , acs.EndTime ) * COALESCE(p.multiplier,1)` would eliminate the need for the `CASE` expression entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(n, acs.StartTime, acs.EndTime) * ISNULL(p.multiplier,1)) AS TotalMins
FROM activecards as acs
LEFT JOIN Promotions as p 
ON acs.StartTime > p.StartTime and acs.EndTime < p.EndTime
```

Comment: this one works , i had to add acs.cid to the select and group by that field to show the totals for each unique cid